# I was asked this in a recent interview q

Tags: c#

I was asked this in a recent interview:

you can use a number or math exprretion not boolean phrase:

```
int x = ???;

while(true)
{
    x=???;
    console.write(x + ",");
}
 Output: 9,2,9,2,9,2...
```

So this answer is not a good one:

```
 int x = 2;
 while(true)
 {
     x = x == 2 ? 9:2;
 }
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think it is not right becaue he is using boolean expresion (x == 2) which was not allowed on interview.

Comment: What a stupid interview question. Are they looking to test your knowledge or just give you brain teasers to figure out how smart you are?

Comment: @slugster It is a little bit naive, but i've worked with quite a few .net developers who don't even acknowledge anything like the XOR solution suggested by xanatos below.

Answer (score 4):

Use the xor (^) operator:

```
int x = 2;

while(true)
{
    x = x ^ 11; // equivalent to x = x ^ 9 ^ 2
    Console.Write(x + ",");
}
```

Because

```
9 ^ 11 == 2
```

and

```
2 ^ 11 == 9
```

Another way, cheating heavily:

```
x = (x / 9) * 2 + 
    (x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 8))) / (-7) * 9;
```

This is based on how int are built and what happens if there is an overflow.

```
(x / 9) * 2
```

if x == 2, then x / 9 == 0, so 0 * 2 == 0

if x == 9, then 9 / 9 == 1, so 1 * 2 == 2

```
(x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 8))) / (-7) * 9
```

if x == 2 then x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 8)) == -7, so -7 / (-7) * 9 == 9

if x == 9, then x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 8)) == 0, so 0 / (-7) * 9 == 0

The two parts are summed together, so 0 + 9 or 2 + 0.

Or clearly

```
x = (x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 1))) / 7 * 2 +
    (x + unchecked((int)(uint.MaxValue - 8))) / (-7) * 9;
```

where we reuse the "overflow" method twice.

In general there are probably many other solutions that are based on this principle: you build an equation that is 0 when x is 2 and is something else when x is 9, and another equation that is 0 when x is 9 and is something else when x is 2. Then you "normalize" the something else to 1 (like the / 7 and / -7 I used) and multiply it by 2 and by 9. Probably you can build something similar with SIN or COS.

(clearly I can't find easy solutions... five minutes later I comprehended that it was useless to use overflows... The minus operator uses the 2 complement of integers directly :-) )

```
x = (x - 2) / 7 * 2 +
    (x - 9) / (-7) * 9;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   int x=2;
   while(true)
   {
    x=11-x;
    console.write(x+",");
   }
```